# Crossfire R7 260X with R9 270X?

Tags: amd-radeon, crossfire

A friend bought me a R7 260X to use with my PC. Long story short, it wasnt powerful enough for my needs and so I went and got an R9 270X that is performing much better.

I have dual PCI-E slots in my rig, I am wondering if I am able to crossfire the R7 card with the R9 card so I can get a total useable 4GB of memory. Is this possible or only able to crossfire within the same series (ie. R9 only with R9).

Comment: What motherboard do you have?

Comment: Have you done any research? @bobSmith1432 is correct, the motherboard is an important factor. Note from [AMD Crossfire site](http://sites.amd.com/us/game/technology/Pages/crossfirex.aspx); "CrossFire™ technology requires an AMD CrossFire™ Ready motherboard, an AMD CrossFire™ Bridge Interconnect (for each additional graphics card) and may require a specialized power supply."

Comment: No it will not work they are not the same cards

Comment: [Oh?](http://sites.amd.com/PublishingImages/Public/Graphic_Illustrations/WebBannerJPEG/AMD_CrossfireX_Chart_1618W.jpg) Could you include more information?

Comment: @BenjiWiebe: Could you post an answer with that in detail? is there a more up to date version with modern cards in it?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't know about a more up-to-date version, I just found that in 10 seconds of Googling to prove person wrong. However, [this](http://www.amd.com/en-us/innovations/software-technologies/dual-graphics) might be more up-to-date and helpful.

Comment: "No it will not work they are not the same cards" is wrong. You do not need *the same* cards, but you do need similar cards (e.g. same generation GPU).  As for a specialised PSU: Nothing specialised about it, you just need enough +12v power and the cables to connect them. (Though most PSU will not come with four 6/8 pin connectors).

Comment: As for memory: Two 2GB cards in crossfire will yield a 2 GB crossfire set (not 4GB). The information is mirrored in the RAM of both cards. Similar theee 2GB cards will yield 3 copies of 2GB usable. It does not add for more RAM,

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (over 25 years of computer maintenance, repair, and building), ATI's (now AMD's) Crossfire platform is designed so that any Crossfire capable card can be linked to any other CF capable card.  HOWEVER, I would recommend that the cards be of a similar generation - R series paired with R series, HD series paired with HD series.  I personally have paired an HD4350 with an HD5750 and had no problems.  I won't say pairing an HD with an R7 or R9 WON'T work, but you should have no problems since you are pairing an R7 with an R9.

Anyway, it's a pointless endeavor if you aren't putting them into a system with an AMD APU (Accelerated Processing Unit) in a motherboard with an FM2+ socket because they WILL NOT get the full benefit of their PCI-e Gen. 3 capabilities.  If the MB is CF capable, they shouldn't have any problems, though.

Answer (score 1):

These answers have no research. No a 260x can not crossfire with a 270x.

http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/amd-crossfire-chart.201045/
"AMD Radeon R9 270X CrossFire compatible with AMD Radeon R9 270X, AMD Radeon HD 7870 and AMD Radeon 7850."

This actually is well known and if you try you'd instantly find that no crossfire will be visible in CCC.

PCI-E gen3 is of no concern at this card level, the benefit of a crossfire compatible card is seen in all benchmark reviews and varies wildly between games from up to 75% improvement in performance to 0% improvement in performance.

Not all crossfire compatible cards can be crossfired with each other. Hybrid crossfire is heavily limited in the recent generations of amd GPU's and is very comparable to nvidia's SLi.

I know this is very old but this is a hit in google results in the top 4. The answer is not just wrong, but misleading in several key areas.

Truth of the matter is, that gen2 at 16x speed is plenty. But neither AMD crossfire nor Nvidia can SLi on 16x pcie gen 2 or gen 3 unless they're paired on an intel 2011 board or a heavily modified intel 1150 board. However with that said, the benefits of both SLi and Crossfire are still huge even with the maximum pcie bus bandwidth restricted.

In the end the answer is no. A 260x can not crossfire with a 270x. If you get a second 270x it's not pointless to crossfire. Your motherboard is important that it needs to be crossfire compatible. Many are.